# manage session on different server and re use parameter from jsp include page to main page

Tags: java, jsp

Two Questions relate to Jsp.

1  session maintain from one server to other.

how to set value in session of jsp file so i will get same value on other server ?

2  if i want to use declared parameter of included jsp to main jsp page then how ?

refer this

```
one.jsp
---------------
   ...
   <%
     String xyz='xyz';
   %>
   ...



two.jsp
---------------
   ...
   <jsp:include file="one.jsp"/>
   <%
    String zbc = xyz;   //can i use this ?
   %>
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for second question-
well i think you will get a compile time error as jsp:include is evaluated at run time. So variable xyz will not be available with two.jsp.

What you can do is store the data  in a javascript variable in one.jsp and access it later on page load from two.jsp.

---

I didn't fully understood your first question. 
Sessions are common across server, so anything stored in it will be accessible to all servers.

You can store attribute to session from jsp using below code.

```
<%= session.setAttribute("xyz", xyz) %>
```

Comment: Your statement about the sessions being shared between all servers is wrong. Either you don't understand how sessions work, or you misplaced the term "server".

Comment: @BalusC can u tell me how session work across two different server ?

Comment: Well the question here is 'what exactly Ruchi means by two different server?'. If she is referring to distributed app, then the session objects are moved across.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you are working over a platform that provides this funcionallity. 
This link will give you a hint about session replication in [glassfish platform](http://javadude.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/glassfish-3-1-%E2%80%93-clustering-tutorial-part2-sessions/)

If your servers aren't part of a cluster, I think you can use a load balancer in front of your server, this element will redirect the client traffic always to the same server, so you don't need to replicate session over nodes.

If this not satisfy your needs, you can storage your session using an external element, like a BD shared cache files, etc.

Hope this help.